# #include <numpy/arrayobject.h> not working in visual studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

When i put #include "numpy/arrayobject.h" on top of my c++-file in visual studio I get "cannot open sourcefile "numpy/arrayobject.h".
I use visual studio 2022 with windows 10 and python 3.9.
How do I install it?

I have searched through stackoverflow and general google answers and it only deals with how to use it when it is installed.

Comment: You have to update your "additional include directories" for your project to specify where you have the `numpy` directory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure that I have numpy installed at all. I have done what you say so that it now works with #Include <Python.h>. Or... I have it installed with python, but I suppose there are no header-files for c/c++ there...

Comment: Yes, that is my question. How to install it with c/c++.

Comment: Using `pip install numpy` from a visual studio command prompt should work or at least `pip` seems to be available for me as it returned `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages`. [https://techcult.com/how-to-install-numpy/](https://techcult.com/how-to-install-numpy/)

Comment: Thanks. I have in installed and it works when I open an interactive python window. But I don't know how to make #include "numpy/arrayobject.h" with a c/c++-file. If I should add it to "additional include directories" I need to know where it is installed. 
Oh, I found it now:
C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy

Thanks!